# Как десериализовать объект на другом ПК?

Tags: java, serialize, сериализация

Я сериализовал класс и отправил его по сети от сервера к клиенту. 
Клиент должен восстановить состояние класса. Как это сделать?

У меня получается только если сериализуемый класс находится там же, где и нужно его восстановить. Пишу `readObject`, все ок. Но у клиента нет доступа к десериализуемому классу, т.е. я создал такой же класс и жду, что `readObject` заполнит `ArrayList` в моем сериализуемом классе. Но он выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.javarush.task.task20.task2019СериализацияКарты.Write.Karta cannot be cast to com.javarush.task.task20.task2019СериализацияКарты.Load.Karta
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас где-то путаница. Ошибка совсем не связана напрямую с сериализацией.

Вот список ошибок сериализации:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/exceptions.html

Ваша же, обыкновенный `ClassCastException`, и из описания понятно почему.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
com.javarush.task.task20.task2019СериализацияКарты.Write.Karta
cannot be cast to
com.javarush.task.task20.task2019СериализацияКарты.Load.Karta
```